# React Native: How to split a file up into multiple files and import them?

Tags: javascript, react-native, libraries, code-reuse, code-structure

I am writing my first app in react native and my js file is getting pretty big. What is the proper way to split the file up.

If i have something like

```
var MyClass = React.createClass({
  ...
})
```

Can I save it at `myclass.js` and include in by some command in another js file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general you can do the following:

```
var MyClass = React.createClass({
    ...
)}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

This way you tell what should be publicly available.

And then, in your former big file you can load the contents like this:

```
var MyClass = require('./myclass.js');
```

Require returns the object that references the value of module.exports.

Comment: nice, thanks. Is it also possible to export more than one class?

Comment: I believe so. Assign MyClass to module.exports.MyClass then import it by calling require('./MyClass.js').MyClass  You will have to do this for each class you assign to exports.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the updated solution with using the `import` statement (in latest React-Native and generally Javascript adhering to ECMAScript6 and later):

file1 myClass.js:

```
export default class myClass {...}
```

file2 app.js:

```
import myClass from './myClass';
```

This is the basic version using a single `default` export. You can also export `named` exports that have to be explicitly listed on import. For more info see [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: the ./ (dot-slash) when importing is important when importing a local file, it fixed my problem. Thanks