# React Native - How to re-use files?

Tags: react-native, code-reuse, code-structure

I have design header, footer video player view, etc as a separate files.
How do I include those in every pages?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923572/react-native-how-to-split-a-file-up-into-multiple-files-and-import-them) method. but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share us the code what so far you have tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

#### Create a file eg: Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Header Component </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

export that component or function to reuse that in other files.

```
export default Header;
```

by exporting that function or class you can import that in any js file by using this:

```
import Header from './Header.js'
```

**OR**

```
import Header from './Header'
```

Here is how you can use that imported component in other files:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Header from './Header'  // import that

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header />  // use like this
        <Text> textInComponent </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

If you have multiple components or function to export in a single file you can't use `export default` in all of that. you just have to use `export` only.

like this: **Common.js** file

```
export Header;
export Button;
```

or you can use that like this.

```
import { Header, Button } from './Common';
```

Comment: Great. Thanks @shashin-bhayani